# How do I set breakpoints looking at assembly?

Tags: assembly, gdb

I have some assembly code and I want to set a breakpoint with gdb when function `abc` gets called, how do I do this?

```
00000000004015c4 <abc>:
  4015c4:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4015c8:   bf 61 28 40 00          mov    $0x402861,%edi
  #more assembly code...
```

Comment: Hm i see, also the line i set a breakpoint at won't run until i say so correct? Or will it run and then pause? @D.Shawley

Comment: Correct. Your program is suspended while you are setting the breakpoint so it won't resume until you tell gdb to resume.